# Get IP of DNS Server in a Windows Server host via Powershell

Tags: powershell, dns, remote-server

I was looking at the [powershell reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/?view=windowsserver2022-ps) for the following need:

I have a remote Windows Server machine hosting a DNS Server. I'm trying to execute remote power-shell commands to obtain the DNS server information using [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/?view=windowsserver2022-ps). However - when Specifying the ComputerName parameter in most of the calls, it seems that providing the remote windows server machine IP is insufficient - it seems like I need to provide the DNS Server IP itself.

Is there a call / set of calls which can help me obtain this data?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the DNS server information"? Are you hoping to discover which DNS server each of your Windows domain members are currently preferring? Or do you want information _from the DNS server itself_?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I want information from the DNS server itself. In order to obtain that information, I need to figure out what's the IP of the DNS server inside my Windows Server machine.

Comment: you mean something like `ipconfig /all`?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Tried it already, I used the value I got there in the command
Get-DnsServer -ComputerName "DnsIPAddress" but it returns an error:
Failed to get server information on "DnsIPAddress" server.

Comment: the remote server IP will be your DNS servers IP. Is PowerShell remoting even enabled? Can you run any other command against it? Can you even ping the IP? Other than that, I believe you're asking on the wrong site. This site is for programming related questions. You should try asking on [Super User](https://www.superuser.com).

Comment: @trizz You can use `Get-NetIPAddress` to get the IP and `Get-DnsClientServerAddress` to get the DNS servers used by your Windows Server host.